# Are the name of the variable and the data itself, both of them stored in the stack?

Tags: stack

My question is : Are the name of the variable and the data itself both stored in the stack?

I would like to know how the name of the variable is linked to the address memory in the stack (the data) and what does it.

Also how does anything know the number of bytes the type of the variable is composed of and how does it decides to read these exact number of bytes in the stack?

Does all the data stored in the stack occupy the same space, no matter the type of data it is?.

And the same questions with the heap?

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/ can answer part of your question

Comment: It is language-specific. May also depend on the implementation. You should specify your language and the environment: compiler etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I believe the following to be true in most practical implementations:

No, the name and actual data are not both stored on the stack.

The compiler keeps track of where the variable is on the stack, and when the compiler is done, all references to the variable (ie the name) has been substituted by a proper increse/decrease of the stack pointer to address the memory area where the data is stored.

No, they do not occupy the same space. A 4 byte var takes up 4 bytes. A 1000000 bytes variable take up 1000000 bytes (but that's not recommended, usually).

The heap is a bit different... Maybe this page can answer your question a bit more: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap

Comment: Hi stackdaemon. Thank you for your sincere and clear answer. And how does the compiler knows if he had to pick 4 bytes or 8 bytes. In the stack there are "plates". So if the standard plate size is 4 bites then he should pick 2 plates. Or could you store "plates" of different sizes?

Comment: It depends on the variable type and how many bytes that type is. If you have an int, for example, you might take ("allocate") four bytes of the stack for it. A short on the ohter hand might only need two bytes. (I write "might" because the byte width of different types could vary from compiler to compiler.) The plates analogy was not very good, I think, in relation to your question. I think it's easier if you just see memory as lots of addressable bytes (or pairs of bytes, depending on granularity of addressing), and the stack as a section of memory.

Comment: It's like, every function has a memory address where it knows the stack starts. Say this address is S. Then int coolVariable1 can be placed at address S. next variable, int anotherCoolVariable, is placed at address S+4 (because coolVariable1 takes up 4 bytes). And in the code, when you have anotherCoolVariable++, the compiler makes  instructions for the computer to increase the value at address S+4 by one.

Comment: Now I understand how it works. I assume when compiler compiles your program base all the directions to the first address of the stack area the program will receive in the RAM. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are not wrong! :)
Also, you might be interested in knowing that the stack pointer is held in a cpu register. See this link for a quick intro to registers: http://www.linfo.org/register.html